# Cauchy residue formula question

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, derivatives, power-series, cauchy-integral-formula

The Cauchy formula can be used to find the $n$th derivative of an analytical function $f(z)$ as
$$
\frac{d^nf}{dz^n}\bigg|_{z=z_0}=\frac{n!}{2\pi i }\oint \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz
$$
which happens to be the coefficients of the Laurent series of $f(z)$.

I have a very similar formula that is given by the following contour integral

$$
\frac{n!}{2\pi i }\oint \frac{f(z^a)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz
$$
However, note the power $z^a$ in the argument of $f(z^a)$. How can I write the left hand side of this function in terms of a derivative? i.e. can we still use the Cauchy formula?

Comment: Apply Cauchy's formulas to $g(z) = f(z^a)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you let $g(z) = f(z^a)$, you can directly apply the Cauchy formula to $g$ and get :
$$\left.\frac{d^ng}{dz^n}\right|_{z=z_0} = \frac{n!}{2\pi}\oint \frac{f(z^a)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}} dz $$